# bottomNavigationBar OnTap does not trigger for navigate to another page

Tags: flutter, dart

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
int selectedPage = 0;
  void changePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      selectedPage = index;
    });
  }
```

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
                showUnselectedLabels: true,
                currentIndex: selectedPage,
                onTap: showPage,
                items: const [
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                      label: 'Main',
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.category_outlined),
                      label: 'Category',
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
                      label: 'Photos',
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                  BottomNavigationBarItem(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.video_call),
                      label: 'Video',
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                ],
```

```
Widget showPage(int selectedPage) {
  if (selectedPage == 0) {
    return NewsViewDetail(id: '0');
  } else if (selectedPage == 1) {
    return NewsLoading(text: 'load');
  }

  return NewsLoading(text: '1');
}
```

When I tap first or second item on the there is no reaction from UI. It seems onTap does not navigate to different pages.

Could you please help me why this code is not working?

Edit: I think the problem causing Scaffold body. Current Scaffold body is:

```
body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  for (final tab in filteredList)
                    NewsView(
                      id: tab.id!,
                    ),
                ],
              ),
```

How can I integrate showPage(_selectedIndex), into Scaffold Body without hurt the TabbarView?

here is the TabBarController

````
return DefaultTabController(
            // length: snapshot.data!.data!.length,
            length: filteredList.length,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: (Colors.white),
                iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
                title: Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(-24.0, 0.0),
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/lo.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 22),
                ),
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: const Size.fromHeight(30.00),
                  child: ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: TabBar(
                        labelColor: Colors.purple[100],
                        indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
                        isScrollable: true,
                        labelPadding:
                            const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                        tabs: tabs),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
    ```
````

Comment: it would be easier to debug if you provide more code.

Comment: you used you tabbar in appbar?

Comment: yes I am using Tabbar in appBar

Comment: updated my answer, I hope you will get an idea of how to solve your problem?

Comment: thanks but for me it is not easy integrate your code with the current structure.

Answer (score 0):

Check it, it will be helped you to solve your solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyNavigationBar(),
    );
  }
}

class MyNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
  MyNavigationBar({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyNavigationBarState createState() => _MyNavigationBarState();
}

class _MyNavigationBarState extends State<MyNavigationBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  void changePage(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  Widget showPage(int selectedPage) {
    if (selectedPage == 0) {
      return Container(
        child: Text('Main Page',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      );
    } else if (selectedPage == 1) {
      return Container(
        child: Text('Category page',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      );
    } else if (selectedPage == 2) {
      return Container(
        child: Text('Photo page',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      );
    }
    return Container(
      child: Text('video Page',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    );
  }

  TabController tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(initialIndex: 0, length: 2, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0),
              //This is for bottom border that is needed
              border:
                  Border(bottom: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 0.8))),
          child: TabBar(
            indicatorWeight: 2,
            controller: tabController,
            indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
            labelColor: Colors.purple,
            unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xff002540).withOpacity(0.7),
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  "First",
                ),
              ),
              Tab(
                child: Text(
                  "Second",
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: TabBarView(controller: tabController, children: [
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: showPage(_selectedIndex),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Center(
                  child: showPage(_selectedIndex),
                ),
              ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      )),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Main',
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.category_outlined),
                label: 'Category',
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.book_online),
                label: 'Photos',
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.video_call),
                label: 'Video',
                backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
          ],
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.shifting,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          iconSize: 40,
          onTap: changePage,
          elevation: 5),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: my scaffold body is busy with Tabbar, I think it is a problem. Current code:
`body: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  for (final tab in filteredList)
                    NewsView(
                      id: tab.id!,
                    ),
                ],
              ),`

Comment: does my code work for you? otherwise, update your question with complete source code.

Comment: I have provided more code. If I change the Scaffold Body with this: showPage(_selectedIndex), everyting is ok but this time my TabbarView does not work

Comment: is there another method to execute this showPage(_selectedIndex) outer scaffold body?